# Window is supposed to close on click, instead closes immediately

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, window

This window is supposed to close when the user clicks the "close" link.  Instead it closes immediately upon opening.  What's the deal?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
img {
    display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 50%;
}
p {
    text-align: center;
}
</style>

 <script 
 src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"> 
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<img src = "assets/images/trophy.png"></img>
<p>YAY!  U R TEH WINZ!</p>
<p><a href = "#" class = "exit">Close.</a></p>
<script>
$(".exit").onClick(this.window.close());    
</script>
</body> 
</html>

<!-- UGH, what is going on?  Either clicking takes you nowhere, or it happens 
right on load! -->
```

Comment: It's the executing order, function arguments are evaluated before calling the function. In this particular case evaluating the argument closes the window. Almost with any other argument you'de get a Type error, `onClick` is not a jQuery method. The correct syntax would be `$(".exit").click((e) => {this.window.close();});`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no onClick event in jQuery. 
So you will be getting following error in your console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).onClick is not a function
```

jQuery .click() event - [Click Here](https://api.jquery.com/click/)

Your event should be as follows:

```
$(".exit").click(function(){
     window.close();
});
```

Comment: Wut? First you say there's no such method, and then you use the same non-existing method saying that shoud be used ..? Also, OP says, that the window is closed immediately, they're not getting an error in that case.

Comment: First of all, I said that there is no .onClick() method. Instead, there is .click() method. And the OP should not have noticed the error in console. There will be definitely an error coming up.

Comment: But you use `onClick` in the example after "_Your event should be as follows:_" ... If the window is closed, there won't be error messages to see.

Comment: I saw the error messages just by doing alert instead of window close to test the event listener. Simple!

Comment: Yup, but still there won't be any errors with the very special case OP has at hands.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @Ankit Rajput in another answer, jQuery has no `onClick` method. It has `click` and `on` though. Thus, instead of `$(...).onClick(...)`, you must write either `$(...).click(...)` or `$(...).on('click', ...)` to even get the proper method call.

Another problem with the original answer is that what's passed as the argument to `onClick` is `this.window.close()`. However, arguments must be evaluated before calling the function, and `this.window.close()` gets evaluated as a function call since that's what is is. Thus, `this.window.close` is called as soon as the script is executed. What you want here is `() => this.window.close()`, which gets evaluated as an anonymous function instead of a function call.

Putting together the solutions to these two separate problems, you end up with something like `$(...).on('click', () => this.window.close())`.